# how to limit the characters and show the remaining characters in php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have been trying to implement to show the remaining characters on php ajax cal.. i got the same thing using javascript but not able to do in ajax php cal.. can any one help me on this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function txtCounters(id,max_length,myelement)
    {
        counter = document.getElementById(id);
        field = document.getElementById(myelement).value;
        field_length = field.length;
        if (field_length <= max_length)  {
            //Calculate remaining characters
            remaining_characters = max_length-field_length;
            //Update the counter on the page
            counter.innerHTML = remaining_characters;
        }
    }
</script>

<label for="txtName">Enter Your Text : </label>
<input type="text" id="txtName" size="50" maxlength="50" onkeyup="javascript:txtCounters('txtCounter',50,'txtName')">
<div id="txtCounter"><b>50</b></div>characters remaining.
```

Comment: What do you have currently in PHP? The code you show does not use PHP, or Ajax.

Comment: yep, i have not implemented... just tried in js.. need to convert the same in php ajax call

Comment: Are you going to use jQuery to help with the Ajax call, or are you planning on using plain JavaScript?

Comment: using jquery need to call an ajax file

Comment: What does php Ajax have to do with it? Makes no sense why you need to make an Ajax call to PHP to check the length.

Comment: need to restrict the characters of text area... the user should not be able to type after reaches limit

Comment: So there is no need for an Ajax call if you want to limit it.

Comment: need to call an ajax file onkeyup

Comment: Why do you need to call a PHP file onkeyup? Just add an Ajax call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is with this handy library: [jQuery.Maxlength](http://pioul.fr/jquery-maxlength)

```
<input type="text" maxlength="50"/>

<script>
$("input").maxlength();
</script>
```

It will automatically include the text characters left by generating this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="50"/>
<div class="maxlength">50 characters left</div>
```

***EDIT***

For some reason you want to use AJAX to do this.

**Web Side**

```
<textarea id="textarea" name="texter"></textarea><br />

<span id="chars_remaining"></span> character(s) remaining.

$( "#textarea" ).keyup(function() {
   var text = $('#textarea').val();
   $.ajax({
      url: "url/to/PHP.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: { text: text },
      cache: false,
      success: function (resp) {
         $('#chars_remaining").html(resp);
      }
   });
});
```

**PHP**

```
  <?php 
  $string = $_POST['text'];
  $length = strlen($string);
  if ((50 - $length) == 0)) {
     echo 'No';
  }
  else {
      echo (50 - $length);
  }
```

Comment: Dont want to use Jquery on this.... i want to implement it on serverside... not in javascript... need to write the restriction code in ajax php file

Comment: Then you're using an AJAX call every time a key is pressed. Why do you need to do this? Just form validate it when it is submitted.

Comment: so an http call for EVERY character entered? That is ridiculously painfully redundant and pointless. just embed the max length somewhere and check it in JS code. that's simple enough. then re-check on the server when the form's submitted.

Comment: @David in the php code block -> `if ((50 - $length) = 0)) {` should be `if ((50 - $length) == 0)) {` -> `==` instead of `=`